# How override property bind name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding

I have 2 model with identical fields:

```
class Model1 
{
    int Prop1 { get; set; }
    int Prop2 { get; set; }
}

class Model2
{
    int Prop1 { get; set; }
    int Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

and main model:

```
class MainModel
{
    Model1 P1 { get; set; }
    Model2 P2 { get; set; }
}
```

I want create `View` for `MainModel`, but don't know what binding data.

Put in the view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.P1.Prop1 ... ) // first editor Prop1, for P1
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.P2.Prop1 ... ) // second editor Prop1, for P2
```

but controller action get value only from first Prop1 editor, for model1 and model2, for model2 value must get from second editor; action:

```
ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Prop1, Prop2")] Model1 model1,[Bind(Include = "Prop1, Prop2")] Model2 model2)
{
}
```

model2.Prop1 value is model1.Prop1 value actually.

What correct bind fields with matching names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*model2.Prop1 value is model1.Prop1 value actually.* No it is not.

Nothing is being bound at all because your property names do not match what your generating in the view. All your property values will be `0` (the default for `int`)

Your method needs to be either

```
public ActionResult Create(MainModel model)
```

or

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Prefix = "P1")]Model1 model1, [Bind(Prefix = "P2")]Model2 model2)
```

The `Prefix` property of `BindAttribute` strips the prefix from the submitted form values so `P1.Prop1` becomes `Prop` for binding

Comment: in question i'm described only fragment of working code, so may i take is not entirely correct fragment

Answer (score 1):

You could use `MainModel` as action parameter:

```
ActionResult Create(MainModel model)
{
}
```

Or you could match parameter names with your main class properties names:

```
ActionResult Create(Model1 p1, Model2 p2)
{
}
```